# Why is the filtering function 'reacting' to the state in the following snippet?

Tags: reactjs

I'm studying React by following Robin Wieruch's *Road to React* and I can't explain why a certain snippet works. Here's the code:

```
const App = () => {
  const stories = [ ... ];
 
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState('');
 
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
 
  const searchedStories = stories.filter(function (story) {
    return story.title.includes(searchTerm);
  });
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Hacker Stories</h1>
 
      <Search onSearch={handleSearch} />
 
      <hr />
 
      <List list={searchedStories} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is working just fine. As I type in the `<input />` rendered by the `<Search />` component, the `<List />` renders a filtered array of `stories`. But I don't understand why or how this is working.

Even though `searchedStories` has been declared only once, it seems to run every time the state (`searchTerm`) is updated. I thought this kind of behaviour could only be achieved by using something like `useEffect`. Anyway, what I can't quite grasp is why the filtering function is reacting to the state.

Comment: The function runs for every render.

Comment: As mentioned, it runs on every render, and the component is re-rendering because the state changed.